# Unable to calculate MD5 hash: /storage/emulated/0/Download/Pdf File/Cofee Hindi.pdf: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Tags: android, android-studio, amazon-s3

My target version is 30 and I am getting "Unable to calculate MD5 hash: /storage/emulated/0/Download/Pdf File/Cofee Hindi.pdf: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)" error when I am trying to upload a user-selected pdf file to amazon s3 I got URI when user select pdf but I got an error when I am trying to upload pdf on amazon s3.

```
intent.setType("application/pdf");                   
                        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
                        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Pdf"), mRequestCodePDFFile);
                        mSelectImageDialog.dismiss();
    
   

        BasicAWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(mid, secretKey);
                                    AmazonS3Client s3 = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);
                                    s3.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.AP_SOUTH_1));
                                    getApplicationContext().startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TransferService.class));
                                    //TransferUtility transferUtility1 = new TransferUtility(s3, CurriculumResponseClassroomActivity.this);
                                    TransferUtility transferUtility = TransferUtility.builder().s3Client(s3).context(CurriculumResponseClassroomActivity.this).build();
                                    TransferObserver observer = transferUtility.upload(
                                            bucket,
                                            storefilename,
                                            new File(mSelectedFinalUploadArray.get(i))
                                    );
        
                                    observer.setTransferListener(new TransferListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onStateChanged(int id, TransferState state) {
                                            try {
                                                if (state == TransferState.COMPLETED) {
                                                    chkCount++;
                                                    ic = chkCount;
                                                    if (pDialog != null) {
                                                        pDialog.setProgress(ic);
                                                    }
                                                    if (count == chkCount) {
                                                        isSuccessfull = true;
                                                        if (pDialog != null) {
                                                            pDialog.dismiss();
                                                        }
                                                        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                                       
                                                    }
                                                } else if (state == TransferState.FAILED) {
                                                  
                                                    if (state == TransferState.FAILED || state == TransferState.WAITING_FOR_NETWORK) {
                                                        // HERE end service and notice user !!!
                                                    }
                                                    if (pDialog != null)
                                                        pDialog.dismiss();
                                                } else {
                                                    Log.e(Tag, "state else 1138" + state);
                                                }
                                            } catch (Exception ex) {
                                                Log.e(Tag, "Error 1139" + ex.getMessage());
                                            }
                                        }
        
                                        @Override
                                        public void onProgressChanged(int id, long bytesCurrent, long bytesTotal) {
                                           
                                        }
        
                                        @Override
                                        public void onError(int id, Exception ex) {
                                           
                                            if (pDialog != null)
                                                pDialog.dismiss();
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
```

Comment: I see no user selected file. Nor can we see how the user selected a file. Start with the selection code please

Comment: intent.setType("application/pdf");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Pdf"), mRequestCodePDFFile);
mSelectImageDialog.dismiss();

Comment: Please put your code in your post. Where it belongs.